# How to efficiently change multiple ids at once, where each id change according to a pattern?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem in HTML, where a lot of elements needs ids. It is very tedious to manually change/set each one. Is there a good way in HTML/JS to generate ids for elements according to a pattern? In the picture below I have the "H1_b" ids that all has to be incremented by 1 so that you get "H2_b" etc...

Best regards

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM5i3.png)

Comment: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and please do not post pictures, paste your actual relevant code

Comment: And where does the OP want the renaming to be happen. Directly at each DOM node within the already rendered html document? Before rendering takes place by replacing IDs directly within the (entire) html code?

Comment: There is likely a more efficient way of structuring this - pls reformat your question per the previous comments

Comment: Sounds like you need to rethink your structure if you're attempting to manage id's like that, but it's really difficult to help you when we have so little info **in the question itself** (not a picture of it)

Comment: btw ... The OP is strongly advised to solve the problem at its very root which is the process that does create HTML code with identical `id` attribute values. Such a value by definition is supposed to be unique.

Comment: An HTML page with duplicate IDs is invalid. See: MDN "The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
let spanIds = document.querySelectorAll('#H1_b');

function iterateIds(x){
    x.forEach(function(item,index){ 
    item.setAttribute('id',`H${index}_b`);
    });
}

iterateIds(spanIds)
```

```html
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H1')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H2')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H3')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H4')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H5')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H6')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H7')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H8')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H9')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H10')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H11')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H12')"></button></span>
    <span id="H1_b"><button onclick="getCard('H13')"></button></span>
```

Comment: hi, @PeterSeliger thank you so much for helping me answer more precisely. I missed the syntax 

Comment: I suppose the issue here is that an ID is allowed to be used on one element only, never duplicated. In other words, the premise is wrong. ...?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to easily defined IDs of a particular tag name:

```
const generateIdsForTagName = (tagName) => {
    const elems = document.querySelectorAll(tagName)
    elems.forEach((elem, i) => elem.setAttribute('id', `${tagName}_${i}`))
} 
// generateIdsForTagName('h1') -> you can see all your h1 will contain different ids
```

Comment: Why would one want to limit the function's usage to tag names only by just naming the function like this. How about passing any (in/valid) selector into it? Why not naming it then `generateIdsForSelectedNodes`?

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over elements.

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].id = "a" + i;
}

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("MAIN")[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<main>
<span>This is a test.</span>
<span>This is a test.</span>
<span>This is a test.</span>
<span>This is a test.</span>
</main>
```